# Understanding OAuth1 Secrets and Signatures

Tags: oauth

I am new to OAuth.

Is a signature the same thing as a secret?

I looked at [this](https://oauth.net/core/1.0/), but still was not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signature is created with a secret, and with other data from your request.

After this signature is created by the client, the server will use the same information to see if the signature was correct.

This allows the server to be sure that the client has a copy of the secret, without requiring the client to actually send the secret.